# Работа с geojson и s2 cells

Tags: json, геолокация, geocoding, geojson

Мне необходимо из geojson получить данные по границам населенных пунктов и после этого определенным образом их обработать. Для этого мне необходимо покрыть получившиеся регионы(внутри границ города/населенного пункта) зонами определенного радиуса которые я далее буду "сканировать".

Я предполагал сделать это путем нахождения координат тайла, в который попадает этот населенный пункт, в проекции меркатора на максимальном уровне зума (для повышения точности) и покрытие этого тайла уже зонами сканирования (зоны сканирования в форме гексов для оптимального заполнения), я понимал что будет избыточное сканирование, но не знал как сделать иначе.

На зарубежном форуме, после услышанной задачи, мне настойчиво порекомендовали использовать S2 cells, для того, что бы оптимально покрыть сканируемую зону и тем самым вообще избавиться от избыточных сканирований. Проблема заключается в том что я:

1. Не смог разобраться в документации на английском что же за зверь эти s2 cells (их принципы построения и т.д.).
2. Не смог найти вообще никакой документации на русском языке, что бы разобраться с этим(вроде гуглом пользоваться умею, действительно то ли на русском языке это называется по другому, то ли что).

Если у кого то есть какая либо документация по данному принципе заполнения пространства то поделитесь пожалуйста ею. Или хотя бы вкратце обрисуйте принципы, тогда возможно разберусь с документацией на английском.

[Репо с s2map визуализатором](https://github.com/blackmad/s2map) если необходимо.

И еще маленький вопрос вдогонку, как адекватно работать с огромными geojson файлами? (1.5ггб и выше). Пока что я пришел только к тому что бы без лишней надобности вообще не шевелить их.

update.

Кажется это связано с деревьями квадрантов, судя по:
[вот этой презентации](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Hl4KapfAENAOf4gv-pSngKwvS_jwNVHRPZTTDzXXn6Q/view#slide=id.i0)

offtopic.

Феномен баадера-майнхофа во всей красе, до сегодняшнего дня ни разу не слышал о деревьях квадрантов и за день уже попадаются в третий раз в абсолютно разных условиях, на корпоративе один из разработчиков рассказывал об их использовании в dx12, затем наткнулся на эту презентации в поисках ответа на свой вопрос и только что читая случайный вопрос на gamedev.stackexchange вновь наткнулся на их упоминание :)

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости когда мне порекомендовали использовать эту библиотеку, то речь шла как раз о использования квадратичных деревьев, c целью разбиения полученных областей на тайлы. А тк разбиение квадрадерева идет по уровня зума (как в проекции меркатора), то я зная размеры ячейки могу просчитать точки для сканирования.

Единственным открытым для меня остается вопрос, посмотрев на пример визуализации[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, почему, тайлы, на которые бьется зона, представлены не в виде квадратов, а ромбами. Что это за искажение и откуда оно берется?

upd. Пока что, жду, может, появятся еще детальные ответы, потому что вопрос для меня лично, абсолютно новый и чем больше советов услышу, тем лучше.

Update. Уровень наклона тайлов зависит от ширины долготы, на экваторе например тайлв рисуются абсолютно ровными квадратами.